# Android Build Path issue?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am baffled by eclipse. I had a working android application which i created inside eclipse. I now have come back to the application after a week and it is saying in the last java files there are hundreds of issue. I am sure there is no programming error inside the files as they worked one week ago. I think it may be a build path issue...i was wondering has anybody else come across this issue and why does it occur??

Several of my other projects also say the last file has errors which i know they dont.

Why is eclipse doing this to me?
Where should the build path point?

Under Java build path-> libraries..it says...unable to get system library for project?

Comment: Can you write which compilation errors are coming in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean build in eclipse. That should generate the R.java and that should resolves your compilation issues.

Comment: I did that several times but did not fix the issue...I looked at where it pointed to the sdk and changed that and that seemed to have done something...however, now where i have R. in the whole project i have errors

Comment: Try right click on the project --> Android tools --> fix project should generate R.java, the generated file. If it does not, then your Android sdk path might have changed or Java SDK is corrupt (less chance). What *.jar are available on your build path? Where is the build path showing red icons?

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens many times to me, here is the way I use to fix it:

1. Export the project to an external folder
2. Delete project from workspace (check "delete files on disk")
3. Import the project into the workspace again (check "copy project files to workspace")

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the SDK location? That may cause this issue.
If possible please post exact error message.

Comment: Yeh ive done that thanks, for some reason it just magically works now

Comment: Whenever you change the SDK location, be sure to update the build path in eclipse. I guess, you had same problem.

Comment: I never changed it, i just pointed it back tot he same place, dont know why it does this, but i will remember this next time